# Underline text in Crystal Report according to value

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report

Can anyone please provide me with the formula required for underlining value of a field in the crystal report according to the value of another field?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps

1. Right click on the field that you want to conditionally underline.
2. From the menu that will appear, select Format Object.
3. From the Format Editor window that will appear, select the Font
   tab.
4. Click the x+2 button which is on the right side of the Underline
   CheckBox.

Insert the following code inside the Formula Editor window.

```
if {TableName.FieldName} = Value then
    true
else
    false
```